# What happens if I created a DAO smart contract and it loses alot of money. Can I get sued?

Tags: dao, legal

In light of what has happened with theDAO and slock.it -- What will happen if I go public with my smart contract as a DAO and collected loads of money from people but then realize it became a loss. Can I as the DAO creator get sued even though a DAO is supposed to be self governing? Assume I'm from New York City. Or would the best course of action to take is to stay anonymous? But then no one would trust my DAO.